# Operations on adjacent elements in a vector

Tags: matlab, vector, operations

I have a binary vector, if I find a `0` in the vector I want to make the adjacent elements `0` if they are not already.

For example if `input = [1 1 0 1 1]` I want to get `output = [1 0 0 0 1]`

I tried the following but it's messy and surely there is a neater way:

```
output=input;
for i = 1:length(input)
    if(input(i) == 0)
        output(i-1)=0;
        output(i+1)=0;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1];  % note that input is a MATLAB function already and thus a bad choice for a variable name
```

Find the zeros:

```
ind_zeros = ~In;  % or In == 0 if you want to be more explicit
```

now find the indicies before and after

```
ind_zeros_dilated = ind_zeros | [ind_zeros(2:end), false] | [false, ind_zeros(1:end-1)]
```

Finally set the neighbours to zero:

```
Out = In;
Out(ind_zeros_dilated) = 0
```

---

For fun, an alternative way to calculate `ind_zeros_dilated` is to use convolution:

```
ind_zeros_dilated = conv(ind_zeros*1, [1,1,1],'same') > 0  %// the `*1` is just a lazy way to cast the logical vector ind_zeros to be of type float
```

Comment: This is a great answer, far better than my attempt! I am sure that avoid "input" as a function will save me hours of debugging in future, thank you very much!